# How to use a global variable for all class methods in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, methods, instance

- I have a `Person` class, which holds an `age` property, now I need to make it accessible in all method inside `Person` class, so that all methods work properly
- My code is as following:

```py
class Person:
    #age = 0
    def __init__(self,initialAge):
        # Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        if(initialAge < 0):
            print("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.")
            age = 0
        age = initialAge

    def amIOld(self):
        # Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console
        if(age < 13):
            print("You are young.")
        elif(age>=13 and age<18):
            print("You are a teenager.")
        else:
            print("You are old.")

    def yearPasses(self):
        # Increment the age of the person in here
        Person.age += 1 # I am having trouble with this method

t = int(input())
for i in range(0, t):
    age = int(input())         
    p = Person(age)  
    p.amIOld()
    for j in range(0, 3):
        p.yearPasses()       
    p.amIOld()
    print("")
```

- `yearPasses()` is supposed to increase the `age` by 1, but now it doesn't do anything when called
- How do I adapt it to make it work?

Comment: @PM2Ring actually, I am new to object programming... didn't even know how to describe my problem ( running away

Comment: OOP is a bit strange at first, but like anything in programming, with enough practice it will soon become familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `age` to be an instance attribute of the Person class. To do that, you use the `self.age` syntax, like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, initialAge):
        # Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        if initialAge < 0:
            print("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.")
            self.age = 0
        self.age = initialAge

    def amIOld(self):
        # Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console
        if self.age < 13:
            print("You are young.")
        elif 13 <= self.age <= 19:
            print("You are a teenager.")
        else:
            print("You are old.")

    def yearPasses(self):
        # Increment the age of the person in here
        self.age += 1 

#test

age = 12
p = Person(age)  

for j in range(9):
    print(j, p.age)
    p.amIOld()
    p.yearPasses()
```

**output**

```
0 12
You are young.
1 13
You are a teenager.
2 14
You are a teenager.
3 15
You are a teenager.
4 16
You are a teenager.
5 17
You are a teenager.
6 18
You are a teenager.
7 19
You are a teenager.
8 20
You are old.
```

---

Your original code had statements like

```
age = initialAge
```

in its methods. That just creates a local object named `age` in the method. Such objects don't exist outside the method, and are cleaned up when the method terminates, so the next time you call the method its old value of `age` has been lost.

`self.age` is an attribute of the class instance. Any method of the class can access and modify that attribute using the `self.age` syntax, and each instance of the class has its own attributes, so when you create multiple instances of the Person class each one will have its own `.age`.

It's also possible to create objects which are attributes of the class itself. That allows all instances of the class to share a single object. Eg,

```
Person.count = 0
```

creates a class attribute named `.count` of the Person class. You can also create a class attribute by putting an assignment statement outside a method. Eg,

```
class Person:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, initialAge):
        Person.count += 1
        # Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        #Etc
```

would keep track of how many Person instances your program has created so far.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly where i was stuck at... I didn't know how to use the same `age` variable in all instances and how `self` works

Comment: OK, thanks. need to teach myself some Object Oriented basics too

Comment: @jm33_m0 Hopefully the new info I've added makes things a little clearer.